# Azure Functions EventHubTrigger C# input binding signatures

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am wondering if there is a C# method signature for the EventHubTrigger input binding containing sort of a context object allowing to Complete, Abandon or Reject EventHub events.
As far as I known such an object exists in the NodeJS version of this binding.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event Hub is effectively a distributed log of events. The low-level operations that it supports are "Append" and "Read events starting at offset X".

You can't Complete or Abandon events in Event Hub. Are you confusing it with Service Bus Queues/Subscriptions?

Comment: Why is it then possible with NodeJS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs "context.done()" or does it have other semantics?

Comment: @Helikaon `context.done()` merely signals the end of function execution, you can't abandon or reject.

Comment: Ok thanks, you got me there in terms of confusing the EventHub with ServiceBus queues and topics